# All script files are requested from wrong url when accessing angular components directly in firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, angular8, firebase-hosting

When I access root url everything works fine. Scripts, favicon and css files are loaded properly as they are requested from below url.

http://localhost:5000/xxxx.ext

eg -http://localhost:5000/styles.e6300255543f91ea72dc.css

But when I access a component route like

http://localhost:5000/technical/create

directly these files are requested from wrong url

http://localhost:5000/technical/xxxx.ext

eg -http://localhost:5000/technical/styles.e6300255543f91ea72dc.css

Because of this resource can't be accessed.

Here is my index.html generated by angular

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>NgKiteAutotrader</title>
  <base href="./">  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.e6300255543f91ea72dc.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script src="runtime-es2015.c5fa8325f89fc516600b.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="runtime-es5.c5fa8325f89fc516600b.js" nomodule defer>

</script><script src="polyfills-es5.3e8196928d184a6e5319.js" nomodule defer></script>
<script src="polyfills-es2015.5b10b8fd823b6392f1fd.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="vendor-es2015.fa47820e09ac01cec997.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="vendor-es5.fa47820e09ac01cec997.js" nomodule defer></script>
<script src="main-es2015.a9ff96b7236696638d6a.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="main-es5.a9ff96b7236696638d6a.js" nomodule defer></script></body>
</html>
```

Command used for building project is

```
ng build --prod --base-href ./ --aot --vendor-chunk --common-chunk --delete-output-path --build-optimizer && tar -zcvf archive.tar.gz dist/*
```

Problem is happening only in firebase.

firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "rewrites":[{
      "source": "/api/:path*",
      "destination": "https://xxxxx.herokuapp.com/api/:path"
    }, {
      "source": "**",
      "destination": "/index.html"
    }],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  },
  "emulators": {
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5000
    },
    "pubsub": {
      "port": 8085
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please make sure the  `base href` is configured correctly。Absolute addresses are recommended，such as: `/`

Comment: I have tried this but doesn't works.

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is solved by changing build command from

ng build --prod --base-href **./**

to

ng build --prod --base-href **/**

If it still doesn't works for you then you can add root(base) url instead of forward slash